# swift: loading array with 300 images

Tags: ios, swift

I have `ViewController` with button. When I press on button I move to `TableViewController` with images in cells. I have array with 300 images.

But when I press on button my app paused for 12-14 seconds to load an array of images. After 14 second I move to `TableViewController`. How to fix it?

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var imageArray: [UIImage] =

            [UIImage(named: "1.jpg")!,
             ...
             UIImage(named: "300.jpg")!]

    var textArray: [String] = ["text1", ... "text300"]

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return textArray
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.cardImageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.label.text = "\(textArray[indexPath.row])"
    }
}
```

Comment: It's likely how you are processing the images that are causing the issue. It's more than likely that you are blocking the main thread that is used to update the UI. Could you add some code to show how exactly you are adding the images to the tableView? Where are the images coming from? Are you just adding them to you are app bundle?

Comment: @paul_f add new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating an array of images straight out why don't you try this:

For numberOfRowsInSection set:

> return 299

Add this method to your Viewcontroller:

```
func loadImageAsync(imageName: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        guard let image = UIImage(named: imageName) else {return}
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(image)
        }
    }
}
```

in your tableView cellForRowAt all you will have to call is:

```
loadImageAsync(imageName: "\(indexPath.row + 1).jpg") { (image) in
        cell.cardImageView.image = image
}
cell.label.text = "text\\(indexPath.row + 1)"
```

It means the app will only have to load the images on demand instead of making a huge array of images that it may never use if the user doesn't scroll all the way down. A 300 image array would be very CPU and memory intensive to create.

Comment: But if user start scrolling fast my app will be freezing?

Comment: No, It should load them on demand. It will be even better if you ensure that the size of the images is appropriate for the device they are being shown on. It may help to add, 1x 2x, 3x images so Xcode can select the appropriate size.

Comment: And if I add 1x 2x, 3x images my app size in App Store will be larger?

Comment: Yes, it may. You may not need it if you are only developing for iPhone. Just try to make sure you aren't showing an unnecessarily large image inside a small space.

Comment: It would be great it if you could vote my answer as correct. Any follow up questions I'm glad to help with here.

Comment: It is works. As I thought, when I start scrolling fast app freezing. I use iPhone X (not simulator). Also app freezing when I start scrolling if I use @RatulSharker answer.

Comment: Okay, 2 mins I will make a new method for you.

Comment: I have created a new method for you called loadImageAsync. This will ensure that the image is loaded from the bundle in an async way. I can't tell you that this is best practise as it is probably not, but it should work. Ideally, you should resize the images to only take up as much size as is required. An image in a small tableView cell should be a few KB.

Comment: In this case images randomly appears in cells. After several seconds images appears in right position. Also size of 1 images = 77 KB. Cell height = 189. All methods have their drawbacks. What method do you recommend?

Comment: I think you need to downsize your images hugely, and then you may not need to user the able loadImageAysnc method. If you were building the same app for Google, they would ensure that the images are the correct size first. There are some really easy and convenient software tools out there to batch change image size, it should only be a 5-minute job. I think that is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the object of `UIImage` in the array, as your code suggested, your images are locally stored as asset, just load the image names.

instead of this

```
var imageArray: [UIImage] =

            [UIImage(named: "1.jpg")!,
             ...
             UIImage(named: "300.jpg")!]
```

Do this

```
var imageNameArray: [String] =

            ["1.jpg",
             ...
             "300.jpg"]
```

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do following

```
cell.cardImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])
```

You could load the image data in background thread, once available then set it. But this approach has several shortcoming. If you do this you have to manually manage the image caching mechanism, because you dont want to load same image twice while shown twice in the cell.

There is a good news for you that, Uiimage(named:) method is thread safe for iOS9+. So if you are targeting iOS9+ you can load the image using UIImage(named:) in background thread. It will automatically manage the caching mechanism

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    // load image here
   let image = UIImage(named......
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // set image here
        cell.card........
    }
}
```

one possible bug may arise in this approach, such that while scrolling fast you may see old images for a while. You could solve it easily by managing the indexpath for which this image was loaded and comparing with current one.

Comment: When I start scrolling fast my tableview app freezing.

Comment: @RatulSharker Yes, I have this bug. I asked question please check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837133/swift-load-the-image-data-in-background

Comment: @RatulSharker so how do I fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should perform some kind of lazy initialization here so you get the benefit of cell reusing.

your code must be like this:

```
var imageTitles: [String] =

        "1.jpg",
         ...
         "300.jpg"]

var textArray: [String] = ["text1", ... "text300"]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return textArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.cardImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageTitles[indexPath.row])
    cell.label.text = textArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: Rather than suggesting an existing answer, supporting the same answer by upvoting the existing answer helps OP to find the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57795252/2143128  @Moaaz